# How to have fan menu enlarge on mouse hover unity UI, (Only on the Pie shape of the menu, not the square image)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I am trying to create a Fan Menu in Unity. Currently, I have a crude fan chart that I was wanting to implement a few basic scripts, such as enlarge on hover and call a function on click. I tried to use OnPointerEnter, but it was triggering on the shape of the square image. I would like the menu option (which isn't rectangular) to only enlarge if it is hovered on, not empty space to the side of it.

```
public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Mouse enter");
        rt = gameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>()
        rt.sizeDelta = startSize * enlargeFactor;
    }
```

This Does trigger, but not on the shape of my fan menu item, but in the square of the image itself. I tried to implement OnMouse events with a collider, instead of OnPointer Events, but nothing was triggering and from [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/998848/onmouseenter-not-working-on-ui-elements.html) I read that they are no longer implemented for UI's in Unity. Does anyone have any ideas as to a good approach to this problem, and a solution[image: Example of a single crude pie chart menu item]
Example of a single crude pie chart menu item

Comment: Try a mask, if that doesn't work, you would need to perform your own mathematical check.

Comment: After messing around a bit, I ended up getting the Alpha Raycaster asset, which does exactly what I need, thanks for your input, and sorry for not getting back sooner.